# How to check if a function ran without generating any errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, boolean

I want to check to see if a message() function ran correctly and managed to send the message, the user could be out of reach for a certain time so I want to script to skip over his name it didn't manage to message him, and to mark the name of people it send a message to

I tried to set a bool value
That changes after the function runs but it doesn't seem to work, i'm using a modular to send the message I recive error on the modular not the script itself

```py
user_was_messaged = False

def message_user()
    user_was_messaged = True
```

Comment: What is a modular?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to return a boolean value from the function? Then you could add the user to your list if the function returns False.

Comment: And if your problem is with identifying if the message was sent or not depending on an error the library you use raised, look into the try/except block

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? If a function "finishes" with an error, an exception will punch through all outer functions unless you *actively* suppress it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `user_was_messaged` variable is global, then you need to use the `global` Python statement to change the value from within your function:

```
user_was_messaged = False

def message_user():
    global user_was_messaged
    user_was_messaged = True
```

However, using a global variable for this purpose would be highly discouraged. Instead, use the return value of the function:

```
def message_user():
    # do things to try to send a message
    if cannot send:
        return False
    # maybe do more things
    return True

if message_user():
    print("successful")
else:
    print("failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have the variable `user_was_messaged` before the function, you must declare the variable as global in the function as in like:

```
user_was_messaged = False

def message_user()
    global user_was_messaged
    user_was_messaged = True
```